# E high string keeps snapping

Tags: guitar, tuning

I bought new nylon strings. I haven't had any problem with my old ones when I tune them, but my high e nylon string keeps snapping out of the pin. It doesn't break, it's fine, but it snaps out of the pin when I tune it and makes my pin fly away. It's hard for me to play now when I can't tune the high e string.

Comment: If your guitar has bridge pins it is designed for ball end steel strings - not nylon strings.

Comment: As Rockin Cowboy says, guitars that use pins to fix the strings in place use ball-end steel strings, not nylon strings. To get you a definitive answer, rather than guesswork, could you please take a picture of your guitar and add it to the post?

Answer (score 4):

What pin could exist in a nylon string guitar?  I am used to those on steel string acoustics.  Usually for nylon strings on a classical guitar you need to literally tie them around the bridge.  For the pin to work the string needs to have a metal bearing at the end.  Even then these will sometimes be under enough tension to pop the peg or pin out.  What I typically do is make sure that the end of the string is bent in a U or J shape.  That ensure that the bearing hooks on the wood under the bridge and doesn't slip up.  This has to be done by hand but is easy.  Just use your thumb nail to bend the end of the string near the bearing twice at 90 degrees.  Then insert the end into the bridge and apply the pin.  You can pull the string with your hand and feel that it catches.  If this is not the "pin" you are referring to or if your nylon strings do not have a bearing at the end then please clarify by adding to your question.

Comment: Well i meant the guitar pin thats what i meant i got it thank you but i dont think this has tp do with the tune has it?

Comment: @Mais, I m confused by your comment.  What peg are you referring to?  The one in the bridge or the tuning mechanism?  If it's slipping from the tuning key then you might have the string wound the wrong way.

Comment: I think you’re on the right track here @ggcg. Really we need a photo to see what type of guitar the OP has.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to tune the string slower. This may be a dumb answer but I tried.

Comment: It helped me actually i can tune it now thanks